# Does the Helm of Brilliance increase damage from a staff spell attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The **Helm of Brilliance** is described in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on page 173, and lists the following as a benefit:

> As long as the helm has at least one fire opal, you can use an action
>   and speak a command word to cause one weapon you are holding to burst
>   into flames. The flames emit bright light in a 10-foot radius and dim
>   light for an additional 10 feet. The flames are harmless to you and
>   the weapon. When you hit with an attack using the blazing weapon, the
>   target takes an extra 1d6 fire damage. The flames last until you use a
>   bonus action to speak the command word again or until you drop or stow
>   the weapon.

My question is as follows:

Does this benefit also apply to spells cast via a magical staff, such as when casting Fireball via a Staff of Power, or would it only apply to melee attacks with the staff?

Comment: Hi Maadiah. When you block-quoted the *Helm of Brilliance* description you made a few errors, capitalizing words that aren't capitalized in the original. Not a big deal for "Bonus Action" or "Command Word," but it's [pretty widely accepted around here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105781/23970) that "action" and "Action" are different in important ways that seem to have affected the answers coming in.

Comment: @nitsua60, I noticed that the Roll20 compendiums often highlight and hyperlink terms of art like "Attack" and "Bonus Action".  I wonder if that's going to be a cause of serious confusion if we're using the capitalization distinction...

Comment: @Icyfire I'd say that's more of an issue Roll20 needs to resolve. The fact that "we're" using the capitalization distinction is because the printed WoTC publications use that distinction (as well as DNDbeyond). The fact that a third party doesn't suggests we shouldn't link to that particular third party

Answer (score 8):

### The bonus damage is limited to attacks

> **When you hit with an attack** using the blazing weapon, the target takes an extra 1d6 fire damage.

It is relevant to know, that **everything that requires an attack roll** to hit is considered an **attack**. In general, this includes melee and ranged attacks with weapons and spells.

A *Fireball* would not benefit from the extra 1d6 fire damage, because it is not an attack.

---

### The bonus damage is limited to *attacks using the weapon*!

Even though spell attacks are considered attacks, they are not using a weapon. The *Helm of Brilliance* limits the extra damage to *"attacks using the blazing weapon"*, in other words weapon attacks.

---

### What if you cast *Ray of Enfeeblement* through the *Staff of Power*

> A black beam of enervating energy springs from your finger toward a creature within range. Make a ranged spell attack against the target.

As per the spell, you are not using a weapon for the attack, thus no extra fire damage. But what happens if you cast the spell **using the weapon?** Is it now a spell attack using the weapon?

I think not. You are casting the spell using the weapon, but the weapon is not part of the spell attack.

---

### All in all

Your *Staff of Power* would only deal the extra damage when you make a *weapon attack* with it.

There are spells, that empower weapon attacks, like *Green-Flame Blade*, *Ensnaring Strike* and a bunch of *Smite* spells limited to the Paladin class. Those would stack with the extra damage.

Comment: this isn't actually accurate to the way that DnD-5e differentiates between "Attack" (as a standard action to attempt to hurt an opponent), and "attack" (a roll to see if you hit).  [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105781/37348) lists in full detail the differences

Comment: Please note that OP originally mis-quoted, writing "Attack" where it should have been "attack."

Comment: @nitsua60 that does actually change the answer, as per the Attack/attack difference and makes this answer correct. (also making my previous comment invalid)

Comment: I think it may also be relevant to include that the fire surrounds the weapon, doing no harm to the wielder or weapon (but implying the flames on it will do damage to others.) Casting a spell from the staff doesn't connect those flames to anyone - only hitting someone with it would. That seems like Intent for it to be for melee attacks.

Comment: In your first explanation, you can say "this includes weapon and spell attacks" because melee and ranged both generally refer to the range at which the attack is being made. In the case of weapons, the type of weapon matters, and spells say which to use.

Comment: @Javelin I wanted to explicitly state that the extra damage is also for ranged attacks because OPs question implies that he thinks it is limited to melee attacks. Rephrased it a bit.

Comment: It seems like the intent is here is that the weapon wreathed in flames needs to make contact in order to deliver the fire damage (melee or ranged.) Casting a spell through it wouldn't move the flames to the target.