# The charger feat as it pertains to combat actions

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature, actions, attack

I am currently playing a Swashbuckler Rogue 5th level. The DM is allowing to pick feats as a variant instead of stats when we level up.

I'm thinking about choosing the *Charger* feat. My question is: When I use that feat to make an attack with my bonus action, does that count as taking the attack action?

Example: I wish to dash 10 feet and use my bonus action to make one melee attack. Could I then make my attack for the turn or would that count as my attack action?

Answer (score 10):

## You could not perform that series of actions.

The reason for this is you only have the option to use only one bonus action and one action on a turn (barring certain exceptions like Action Surge or Haste).

- If you take the Dash action as your action for the turn, then you
  could make the bonus action attack with the Charger feat but you will
  have already used your action to Dash so you cannot take the Attack
  action.
- If you use Cunning Action to Dash, you will have already used your bonus action so you cannot make the Charger attack, but you could then use the Attack action.

### The bonus action attack from Charger does not count as an Attack action

See [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/what-does-upper-case-a-attack-action-vs-lower-case-a-attack-mean) for clarity on the difference between an attack and the Attack action

Answer (score 1):

You get:

- One action on your turn
- One bonus action on your turn
- Can move up to your speed on your turn
- One reaction on your turn or before your next turn.

Charger says:

> When you use your action to Dash ...

So you have used your one and only action to Dash, which allows you to use your one and only bonus action to make an attack.

You cannot also take the Attack action (because you used your action to Dash). You cannot trigger Charger using your Rogue's Cunning Action (because that uses your bonus action and you have not met Charger's condition "use your *action* to Dash" and also, you wouldn't have a bonus action).

Answer (score 1):

You do not take a move action at the end of his chain of events but rather you finish moving any amount you have left from your earlier Dash action.  An example is as follows:

Your character has 30 ft of movement.

Action - Dash:  By taking the Dash Action you double your speed, so you have 60 ft of movement available to you to begin with.  Lets say it takes 20 ft to reach your target for this example.

Bonus Action - Attack your target with +5 damage from Charger Feat + Sneak Attack if conditions are met

Since you only moved 20 ft to reach your target, you can finish moving around if you so wished with the remaining 40 ft.

Comment: This appears to be close to answering the question.  Is the attack you listed under bonus action count as the Attack Action? or is it a melee attack as a Bonus Action?

Answer (score -3):

Swashbuckler can move away from an opponent without drawing AoO as long as they make a melee attack. So a swashbuckler with charger can charge in, use bonus action to melee with the +5 (plus sneak attack) then use movement to get away without drawing AoO.

Action - dash at least 10 ft.

Bonus action - charger attack =+5 damage +sneak attack if conditions met

move action - move speed away.

Comment: As stated in the other two answers, this doesn't work due to the action economy and the fact that the Bonus Action attack *does not* count as taking the Attack Action. *If* you have found a way for this to work then please [edit] in more information about and explain *how* it works.

Comment: You don't get 2 attacks, but you can dash in, get the +5 and sneak attack and move away without drawing AoO.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to further explain how this works then.

Comment: Action - dash at least 10 ft.    Bonus action - charger attack =+5 damage +sneak attack if conditions met       move action - move speed away.

Comment: Justin, please edit that information into your actual answer, not as a comment.