# Can War Priest and Precision Attack both be used on the same attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, fighter, battle-master

I am playing a level 4 character: Cleric, War Domain (1) and Fighter Battle Master (3).

The War Domain's **War Priest** feature is described as follows:

> From 1st level, your god delivers bolts of inspiration to you while you are engaged in battle. When you use the Attack action, you can make one weapon attack as a bonus action. You can use this feature a number of times equal to your Wisdom modifier (a minimum of once). You regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

The description of the Battle Master's **Precision Attack** feature:

> When you make a weapon attack roll against a creature, you can expend one superiority to add to the roll. You can use this maneuver before or after making the attack roll, but before any effects of the attack are applied.

The question:
Can both features be used in the same attack, or must they be used on separate independent attacks?

Comment: Are you playing a level 2 character? If so, it's impossible to be a Battle Master Fighter; per the Fighter's class description, you can't choose a Martial Archetype until level 3. Once you clarify what you mean, we can answer your question.

Comment: to follow up on @V2Blast's comment, you'd need to be at least 4th level (cleric 1 and fighter 3) to use the features you described in the question.

Comment: I did not know it should be at level 3. Still, assuming you have the correct level and everything you need to have both skills, would they apply in the same attack?

I'm looking at the warrior rules where level 3 appears and I do not see it, if you indicate where I am I would also be very grateful. I am new with these rules, before I played with Player's Options.

Comment: I edited the question to use the proper level; since you still want to know how this would work and it's a valid question this way. The trait that lets you become a Battlemaster is called "Martial Archetype" and you get it at level 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, you can stack those abilities

As you quoted, the use of the War Priest is a limited resource that also requires the use of a Bonus Action. This means that you are limited in how many times you can use it (based on your Wisdom modifier) and also that it requires your Bonus Action (You only get one bonus action per turn).

The Precision Attack uses your limited resource of Superiority Die, but it does not complete with your Bonus Action usage or anything else.

In your case, if you use an Attack action you can use your Bonus Action to make another weapon attack. If you had enough Superiority Dice available, you could use them on both attacks.

Comment: Now I have understood it. Everything clarified perfectly. Many thanks.

Comment: @YUGULO Glad I could help - and welcome to the stack!

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, you can use both in the same turn.

That said, the two abilities wouldn't exactly apply to "one attack", since they have slightly different triggers and work in different ways.

The War Priest feature lets you make one weapon attack as a bonus action if you use your action to do the Attack action.

In contrast, the Precision Attack maneuver applies to any single attack roll. (See [this thread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/what-does-upper-case-a-attack-action-vs-lower-case-a-attack-mean) for the distinction between an attack (or attack roll) and the Attack action.) It lets you expend a superiority die to add the amount on the superiority die to your to-hit roll for one attack roll. You could do this on any of the attacks you get on your Attack action (you'd get more attacks per Attack action at higher levels as a Fighter) or on the single bonus action attack you get through the War Priest feature.

The two features are limited by different things: War Priest by your Wisdom modifier, Precision Attack by your number of superiority dice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, especially for explaining in such a detailed way the reasons. Looking at the details is what really clarifies the issue.

Comment: @YUGULO Glad to help!