# Would a cantrip like firebolt count as an attack to be able to use Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, attack, fighter

I am currently a level 5 fighter going with Eldritch Knight in a campaign. My friend says that when I use a spell like firebolt to attack an enemy, it does not count as an attack and I cannot use my Extra Attack feature from my class.

It was my understanding that when I hit level 7 I would be able to use a cantrip to attack, then get a bonus melee attack for War Magic, and then use my Extra Attack to attack again, doing the same thing. But according to my friend, once I use any spell I cannot use my Extra Attack ability due to it not being an Attack action only using an action to cast the spell. Is he right?

Answer (score 16):

Extra Attack states:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, **whenever you take the Attack action** on your turn.

Casting a spell uses the *Cast a Spell* action, not the Attack action. Therefore you can't cast a spell as your extra attack.

Comment: Yep. In addition, Fire Bolt is "an attack", since it involves an attack roll, but it is not "the Attack action". (The difference is explained in [this RPG.SE thread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/what-does-upper-case-a-attack-action-vs-lower-case-a-attack-mean).)

Comment: Perhaps wording it like "using your action to make and attack, vs using your action to cast a spell"\

Answer (score 6):

### No to Extra Attacks, and no to two "bonus attacks"

1.) (As previously stated) Extra Attack only gives you the ability to attack more than once when you take the Attack Action on your turn. Although Firebolt involves "an attack", it is not the Attack action.

2.) You said you wanted to attack, get a bonus attack, and then attack again "doing the same thing" (presumably from War Magic, which lets you attack with a bonus action when you use an action to cast a cantrip). Although you could use your Action Surge to cast Firebolt twice, you could only get one bonus action weapon attack total on your turn, since you only get one bonus action per turn (and only on your turn).