# Critically Hit while Paralyzed

Tags: dnd-5e, critical-hit

I understand the Rogue Surprise Attack PLUS a Critical Hit results in extra dice and double dice as these are different effects, but what about a Critical Hit on a Critical Hit?

Paralysis renders:

> - Attack rolls against the creature have advantage.
> - Any Attack that hits the creature is a Critical Hit if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature.

Since a Critical Hit "Condition" is already in effect, does a Critical Hit on the d20 roll re-double these dice?

Example: A Paralyzed gnoll is attacked by a longsword. Character rolls a 6 and a 20, a Critical Hit. Damage = (d8+d8)+bonuses, or (d8+d8)+(d8+d8)+bonuses?

Comment: Thief Surprise Attack? Do you mean Rogue Sneak Attack?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### No

A hit is either critical or not; there are no rules providing for "degrees" of criticality. The normal condition for critical hits is rolling a 20 on the d20 without modifiers on one's attack roll - a "natural twenty".

The paralysis effect simply extends that condition. Now any attack (with a [lowercase-a](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/what-does-upper-case-a-attack-action-vs-lower-case-a-attack-mean/)) that hits is resolved as a critical hit, natural 20 or otherwise, so dice are rolled twice for damage.