# Action Surge question

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, attack, fighter

The *Player's Handbook* says that Action Surge grants one additional action on your turn, once per short or long rest.

The Extra Attack section of the PHB says that at level 11 (for example) when you use the "Attack action", you can attack three time per turn.   If Action Surge grants one additional action, and I choose the "Attack action", does that mean I would get three more attacks with Action Surge?

In other words, if I use the "Attack action" for my normal action (3 attacks) and use "Attack" again for my Action Surge action (3 attacks), would I get 6 attacks on that turn?

Comment: Sorry - I guess I should be more specific - this is D&D 5e, Fighter class.

Comment: I think your question [is a duplicate of that one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121878/22566).  Being duplicate is not a bad thing, there is more than one way to ask the same question.