# Can I use an extra attack when using war magic for a bonus attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, fighter

I’m nearly level 7 as an Eldritch knight. Because of that, I’m planning how to do the most damage as I can to defeat a very threatening and greedy party member so obviously being an Eldritch knight will probably help in this situation.

I’m planning out a move that uses a combination of my extra attack I got from level 5 as a fighter, and my action surge from level 2. If I was level 7 though, I would get to use war magic which states that I can use a cantrip and still have the ability to attack as a bonus action. I just don’t know if my extra attack applies to that bonus attack. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [War Magic and Extra Attack? Can it work?](/questions/82977) and [Can I use extra attack as the bonus action to improved war magic to get 2 hits and a spell?](/questions/61803), which are duplicates of [What does upper-case-A-Attack action vs. lower-case-a-attack mean?](/questions/105781)

Comment: @Eimsmaul I think you might want to consider about asking a new question just about that aspect. Because I can tell you for free that PvP fighting is not going to solve your issue, it is only going to escalate things. Ask about it in a new question with more details and we can help you fix this issue hopefully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### War Magic only allows a single attack even if you have Extra Attack

Extra Attack is a feature that only grants you more attacks specifically when you take the Attack Action:

> whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

However, War Magic is not granting you an Attack action, it is granting you a single weapon attack (emphasis mine):

> Beginning at 7th level, when you use your action to cast a cantrip, you can make **one weapon attack** as a bonus action.

Action Surge, however, interacts differently with Extra Attack. You can see more on that in [this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121878/33707)

### PvP in D&D is an entirely different issue

Noting that you mention you want to use this on another player and from the comments to the question, it seems you are having issues with another player. I recommend asking a separate question to get advice on how to work these out.

Comment: The wording about Action Surge in your answer is a bit confusing. I assume what you mean is that if you use Action Surge, you could use one action to cast a cantrip, use Action Surge and use your second action to take the Attack action, and use your bonus action to make one more weapon attack.

Comment: Ah I was simply referring to the fact that Action surge does allow you to take a full Attack action and thus get the Extra Attacks on that specific action. Since there is a question on that already, I thought I would not repeat the full explanation and just link to it instead. I agree it may not be clear, I will try to improve it.

Comment: @V2Blast I couldn't make it less confusing considering the rest of the question so I think I will just fully defer to the related question on this

Answer (score 6):

### No, bonus action attacks are not the "attack action"

Using a bonus action to attack is different from taking the Attack Action. You only gain additional attacks from Extra Attack under the following circumstances (PHB, p. 72, italics added):

> **Extra Attack** You can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take *the Attack action* on your turn.

Comment: 1) it might help to quote the relevant parts of Extra Attack (and probably the attack vs Attack Q&A here) for extra clarity. 2) you might consider addressing the PvP aspect of the question seeing as it seems that they are having table issues.

Comment: The PVP issue is troubling to me, but as the question didn't ask "how do I best deal with a player I think I have to kill" or something like that, I feel it might be overreaching for me to address that. I'll give it some thought.

Comment: yeah that is totally your call. Just thought I'd mention it. It would obviously be going a few extra steps beyond what they actually asked, but on the other hand, such advice might solve their actual issue. Again, up to you obviously +1 either way.