# Can a Swords bard benefit from Blade Flourish's speed increase again if they take the Attack action again?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard, stacking

The Swords Bard's 3rd level feature, Blade Flourish, states:

> [...] Whenever you take the Attack action on your turn, your walking speed increases by 10 feet until the end of the turn [...]

So if a Bard took the Attack action multiple times (through something like [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) or [Action Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ActionSurge-193)) would they gain the speed increase multiple times as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The speed increase will stack because the effect does not have a duration

The [*Dungeon Master's Guide* errata](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/errata-november-2018) ([pdf link](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DMG-Errata.pdf)) added the "Combining Game Effects" section which states (emphasis mine):

> Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply **while the durations of the effects overlap**. [...] **Game features include** spells, **class features**, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items. [...]

Since game features include class features one would think that we can conclude that two instances of Blade Flourish's speed increase would not stack; but in this case, *there is no overlapping duration*. We can conclude this by looking to the *Essentials Kit*, which includes a "Effects with the Same Name Don't Stack" section (page 3) stating (emphasis mine):

> [...] But when two or more effects have the same proper name, only one of them applies while the durations of the effects overlap **(a duration is a time span of 1 round or more)**. [...]

This defines what counts as a duration and in this case, the Blade Flourish's speed increase lasts *until the end of the current turn* (less than 1 round), thus you can benefit from the speed increase multiple times if you took multiple Attack actions.

---

Small sidenote:

The Bard's feature triggers "whenever" you take the Attack action, this means that it occurs every time you take the Attack action, similar to how [Extra Attack triggers every time you take the Attack action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121878). If the rules wanted "whenever" to mean only the first time or only once they would use "the first time you take the Attack action" or state that the speed increase can occur only once per turn like they do with many other features.

Comment: @NautArch That is not true, it explicitly does.

Comment: @naut *haste* grants an additional limited use action, one option is taking the Attack action though it must be only one weapon attack (so no grapple/shove, radiant sun bolt (from Monk), benefitting from Extra Attack, Dread Ambusher, Stalker's Flurry or anything similar that adds to the Attack action itself)

Comment: @Cubic You're right! I was thinking about the single attack, not that you get a very specific Attack.

Comment: A new rule in the essentials kit seems to me to seriously contradict the no hidden rules thing, that's a pretty unlikely book for experienced players to buy and read

Comment: @serious Well I was already arguing that things that affected a single roll had no duration, since duration wasn't defined at all. Now I guess it's just expanded to things ending on the current turn in general which... Yeah, is rather hidden. IIRC it also Includes the "Use A Magic Item" action

Answer (score -1):

### It depends how your DM parses “Whenever you take the Attack action on your turn”

It’s an odd phrase because AFIK, if it isn’t your turn, you can’t take the Attack action. So, what is the point of including “on your turn”? The only thing I can think of is they are trying (and failing) to make it clear that it doesn’t matter whether you take the Attack action before or after you move.

Notwithstanding, we need to focus on the word [whenever](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whenever) and what it means:

> 1. at whatever time
> 2. at any or every time that

If we use the first then *if* you take any number of “Attack action on your turn, your walking speed increases by 10 feet until the end of the turn”. Therefore you only get it once.

If we use the second definition then, *each* time “you take the Attack action on your turn, your walking speed increases by 10 feet until the end of the turn”. Therefore you get it once per Attack action.

Neither interpretation is obviously wrong so it’s DM’s call.