# If the UA artificer casts an attack cantrip from a wand, is that considered an "Attack action made with a magic weapon"?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, attack, unearthed-arcana, artificer

So I'm looking at the [Artificer Revisited Unearthed Arcana](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/artificer-revisited) ([PDF direct link](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer-2019.pdf)).

The 5th-level Arcane Armament feature says if you make an Attack action using a magic weapon, you can attack twice in that action. I'm interested in making an Artificer who is a wielder of wands primarily, but I'm wondering if this feature would not apply to wands.

If the artificer casts an attack cantrip from a wand, is that considered an "Attack action made with a magic weapon"?

Answer (score 14):

### Nope

It depends on the wand, but usually, it is not an *Attack action*.

For instance, the Wand of Magic Missiles requires you to "use an action", not "take an Attack action":

> This wand has 7 charges. While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 or more of its charges to cast the magic missile spell from it.

Even if the wand's spell requires you to "make a ranged spell attack" it still won't be an *Attack action*, which is a specific term in 5e. For more details, see: [What does upper-case-A-Attack action vs. lower-case-a-attack mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/)

Comment: Maybe add something about, although some spells will require a spell attack, that’s stil not an Attack action.