# Do you only get one attack with the Mobile feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, attack

I was in a game and I just got the Mobile feat so I go up to the enemy and I hit him like a wrecking ball (I have a Flame Tongue Greatsword infused into my body which is only for flavor reasons).

The third benefit of the [Mobile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/mobile) feat (PHB, p. 168) says:

> - When you make a melee attack against a creature, you don't provoke opportunity attacks from that creature for the rest of the turn, whether you hit or not.

Can I make more attacks if I have Extra Attack, or am I only allowed to take one Attack action? Because it doesn't state that in the feat.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Could you clarify what about the feat makes you think it changes the number of attacks you can make on your turn? If we know that, we can help clarify your point of confusion.

Answer (score 14):

The feat doesn't limit the amount of attacks you can make. It only states that whenever you make a melee attack against a creature, you don't provoke opportunity attacks from that creature for the rest of the turn. In fact, multiple attacks work quite well with this: if you are adjacent to two enemies, you can make one attack against each and then leave their reach without provoking an opportunity attack from either!

> Can I make more attacks if I have Extra Attack, or am I only allowed to take one Attack action?

In most cases, even if you have Extra Attack, you will only take at most one **Attack action** during your turn. Extra Attack doesn't grant you additional Attack actions, but increases the amount of attacks you can make whenever you take said action. Note that Mobile feat's bonus triggers off any melee attack, including melee spell attacks, opportunity attacks and other attacks made without using the Attack action.

The distinction between the Attack action and an attack as a game mechanic is notable as there are features that are triggered by taking the Attack action as well as features that are triggered by making attacks --- see [this question and its answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/what-does-upper-case-a-attack-action-vs-lower-case-a-attack-mean/) for more information about the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

### You can make as many attacks as you normally could

The particular aspect of the feat in question only limits how many attacks that the opponent can make - in this case, if you hit the creature with a melee attack, it can no longer make opportunity attacks against you. You may be confusing this with similar abilities, which allow you to use your Attack action to do something else in place of attacking.

In short, your amount of attacks is unaffected, this feat serves only to make such melee attacks a little better.