# Ruling for Grappling a Creature Underwater While you are on Land?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, grapple, underwater

If a character is on the bank of a river and they want to reach into the water and grapple a creature in the water (assuming that they are within the size limit to be grappled) are there any special rulings for grappling or is it the standard grapple check?

According to the Grappling Rule as listed on *[Roll20](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Combat#content)*

**Grappling**

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the Attack action to make a Special melee Attack, a grapple. If you’re able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this Attack replaces one of them.
> The target of your grapple must be no more than one size larger than you and must be within your reach. Using at least one free hand, you try to seize the target by making a grapple check instead of an Attack roll: a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the target’s Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check (the target chooses the ability to use). If you succeed, you subject the target to the Grappled condition (see Conditions ). The condition specifies the things that end it, and you can release the target whenever you like (no action required).

But when you look at Under Water Combat on *[Roll20](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Combat#content)*

**Underwater Combat**

> When making a **melee weapon Attack**, a creature that doesn’t have a swimming speed (either natural or granted by magic) has disadvantage on the Attack roll unless the weapon is a Dagger, Javelin, Shortsword, spear, or Trident.
> A **ranged weapon Attack** automatically misses a target beyond the weapon’s normal range. Even against a target within normal range, the Attack roll has disadvantage unless the weapon is a crossbow, a net, or a weapon that is Thrown like a Javelin (including a spear, Trident, or dart).

It appears there is no clear ruling and that the standard grapple check applies. Is that correct?

Comment: You may want to cite the rules on D&D Beyond or another source instead, as [Roll20's compendium is full of incorrect capitalization](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8218/how-to-handle-incorrect-quotations-from-3rd-party-sources) - in particular, [the improper capitalization of "attack" when not referring to the action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/what-does-upper-case-a-attack-action-vs-lower-case-a-attack-mean) can result in confusion.

Comment: Duly noted for next time, didn't have my PHB to hand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Only melee/ranged weapon attacks are affected by being underwater, grappling is not a melee or ranged weapon attack

The rules on "[Underwater Combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#UnderwaterCombat)" state:

> When making a melee weapon attack, a creature that doesn’t have a swimming speed (either natural or granted by magic) has disadvantage on the attack roll

Meanwhile the rules on ["Grappling"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) state:

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the Attack action to make a **special melee attack**, a grapple. If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.

Weapons attack require you to use a weapon unless there is a specific exception in the rule like with unarmed strike. Grapples (and shoves) count as melee attacks, but do not count as weapon attacks as they do not actually involve using a weapon.

No section of the rules on grappling state that being underwater would impose disadvantage and so you would not have disadvantage when underwater and similarly you would not have disadvantage when only your target is underwater.