# Eldritch knight dual wield: do I get multiple attacks on my bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, two-weapon-fighting, eldritch-knight

I have a level 11 Eldritch Knight with two weapon fighting.

The rules say I have 3 attacks per action.

The rules say when ever I make an attack action with my main hand I can make a bonus attack action with my offhand.

Does that mean I get 3 attacks on my off hand as well?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance.

Comment: Some related questions (maybe a duplicate somewhere): "[Does it matter which weapon I attack with first when two-weapon fighting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132221)" and "[How many attacks exactly do I get if I combine the Dual Wielder feat with the Two-Weapon Fighting fighting style?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154788)" and "[Order of attacks when using Two Weapon Fighting and Extra Attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162435)" and "[Can you use your off-handed weapon for your main attack action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164342)"

Comment: Also strongly related: [uppercase-A-Attack vs. lowercase-a-attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105781/23970).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### No; what the rules actually say is *one bonus action per turn*

We will frame this answer using the action economy as written in Chapter 9.  {my italics and bolding throughout}

> **Your Turn**
>   On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed *and take one
>   action*.

As you state, you will take the Attack action (rather than perhaps the Dash, Disengage, or Dodge action)

> Bonus Actions
>   You can take only ***one bonus action*** on your turn, so you must choose
>   which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.   You
>   choose when to take a bonus action during your turn...

You want your bonus action to be the one for two weapon fighting.

Two-Weapon Fighting (Chapter 9)

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon
>   that you're holding in one hand, you can use ***a*** bonus action to attack
>   with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other
>   hand.  You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus
>   attack, unless that modifier is negative.

But since you have this fighting style (Chapter 3) ...

> Two-Weapon Fighting.  When you engage in two-weapon fighting, you can
>   add your ability modifier to the damage of the second attack.

... you do apply your damage bonus.

The Action is attack; a Fighter 11 gets two extra attacks when you make that attack as an action.   A Barbarian 11 would only get one extra attack.

- Extra Attack is a class feature that adds attack(s) to the generic attack action.  You are not taking multiple actions; you are taking one action, attack, but you get to roll for more chances for making an effective attack that does damage.  A wizard could not do this. (Wrong class).

Attack  (Ch 9)

> The most common action to take in combat is the Attack action, whether
>   you are swinging a sword, firing an arrow from a bow, or brawling with
>   your fists.   With this action, you make **one melee or ranged attack**.
>   {snip}
>   Certain features, such as the Extra Attack feature of the fighter,
>   allow you to *make more than one attack with this action*.

An *Action* is a different thing from a *bonus action*. (Yes, that can be confusing)  Here is how bonus actions work - in your turn, after you take your action, or before, you get to take **one bonus action**. From the CH 9 two weapon fighting rule ...

> you can use *a bonus action* to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand.

A is singular, and that attack is not the same as the Attack (Action) since it is a bonus action.

So what happens is this:
You choose to make the Attack action, so you attack  and add two extra attacks for your high level - total of three attack rolls for this turn's attack Action.
You can add **one bonus action attack** with the other weapon - total of four for this turn.

Note that "offhand" isn't addressed in this edition of the game: that term is a carry over from earlier editions.

Comment: Thanks for this very in depth answer to my question. The way you explain this totally removes all confusion I had on this subject. Thanks for that. 5 gold stars from me

Answer (score 5):

## RAW, no.

> PHB pg189
>
> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so
> you must choose which bonus action to use when you
> have more than one available.

Specific over general.  The rules state that you receive your movement, one *action*, one *bonus action*, and one *reaction* .

> If a specific rule contraddicts a general rule, the specific rule wins.

The multiattacks are an example of a specific rule breaking the general rule outlined in the Player's Hamdbook.  Furthermore, the specific rule is only mentioning the Attack Action.  There is no wording to assume a further inclusion of the Bonus Action as well.