# With only one free hand, can I still cast spells with somatic components?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spell-components, shield

I have a doubt about this. I have had various answers and they contradict each other so I would like some clarity on this.

I am a Cleric, I have a shield (which is also my focus), I want to wear my shield in battle to benefit from the +2 AC and I want to be able to cast spells. I'm not holding anything in my free hand.

**Is a Cleric who is a) proficient in Shields and b) trying to cast a spell with a somatic component able to do so, if they only have one hand free?**

That is, without having to doff the shield and suffering an **AC penalty**. I seem to remember there being a rule about needing to have **at least one hand free** to cast spells?

Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Does the spell in question also have a material component? This is important sometimes though I don't think it is in this particular case. Also is the War Caster feat involved?

Comment: Related: "[Casting a Somatic, non-Material spell while holding a focus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105480)" and "[Can a wizard using an arcane focus quarterstaff and a shield still cast somatic component spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105402)" and "[How do foci and somatic+material components interact when it comes to occupying a hand?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46201)" and "[Can I cast spells that require a material component and still hold my hammer and shield?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51976)"

Comment: *"I'm not holding anything in my free hand"* — so you have your shield in one hand, and the other one is free, is it correct?

Comment: @enkryptor Yes, and my Cleric's focus is my shield.

Comment: @ETgothome so what is your concern? *"a rule about needing to have at least one hand free to cast spells"* — you have one free hand, what's the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes

Spellcasting only requires the use of one hand.

> **Somatic (S)**
>   Spellcasting gestures might include a forceful gesticulation or an intricate set of gestures. If a spell requires a somatic component, the caster must have free use of at least one hand to perform these gestures.

Source: [5e SRD](https://www.5esrd.com/spellcasting/)

Note that you don’t necessarily need a free hand; The rules on material components imply you can use the hand holding your spellcasting focus (in your case, your shield) to perform somatic components:

> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell’s material components—or to hold a spellcasting focus—but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components.

Answering the last bit of the question:

> I seem to remember there being a rule about needing to have at least one hand free to cast spells?

Yes, but only for spells requiring (S) components. There is no general rule that *all* spells require a free hand, and there are plenty of rules without somatic components such as [Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)

Note that the 5e SRD is official material published by WoTC, but the website I’ve linked to itself is not run by WoTC; Rather it is a more convenient display for [this](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf) official WoTC document published under the OGL.

Comment: You may wish to clarify whether the focus interaction is only valid if the spell also has a material component

Comment: @NautArch I did link to the source PDF. I haven’t referenced the PHB directly because I don’t have it with me right now.

Comment: Technically, the SRD isn't a rules resource anyway, but rather a document detailing what content can be legally distributed by others using the OGL. (It also hasn't been updated since 2016.) You might be better off linking to the basic rules, whether on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Components) (an officially licensed distributor of official 5e content) or the [original PDF from WotC](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

Directly from the [PHB pg 203](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#SomaticS) (emphasis mine) when discussing somatic(S) spell components:

> Spellcasting gestures might include a forceful
>   gesticulation or an intricate set of gestures. If a spell
>   requires a somatic component, the caster must have **free
>   use of at least one hand** to perform these gestures

Therefore if your character is holding a shield, in one hand and their other hand was empty, they would be able to cast spells that included somatic components.

For your case, where your shield is your spell casting focus, you do not even need a free hand. Also stated on the same PHB page mentioned above (emphasis mine) under the Material (M) component section it states:

> A spellcaster **must have a hand free** to access a spell’s material components—or **to hold a spellcasting focus**—but it **can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components**.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer provides the solution, but I'd like to add that an example about a cleric wearing a mace and a shield was used [in Sage Advice](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA165) to explain that it's possible to hold both items to cast a **somatic and material** spell:

> A cleric’s holy symbol is emblazoned on her shield. She likes to wade
> into melee combat with a mace in one hand and a shield in the other.
> She uses the holy symbol as her spellcasting focus, so she needs to
> have the shield in hand when she casts a cleric spell that has a
> material component. If the spell, such as aid, also has a somatic
> component, she can perform that component with the shield hand and
> keep holding the mace in the other.

Additionally, **and pertinent to the original question**, the aforementioned response in [Sage Advice](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA165) offers an example of a spell with **only the somatic component**:

> If the same cleric casts cure wounds, she needs to put the mace or the
> shield away, because that spell doesn’t have a material component but
> does have a somatic component. She’s going to need a free hand to make
> the spell’s gestures. If she had the War Caster feat, she could ignore
> this restriction.

Comment: Good addition. I think it still would be good to also directly answer the actual question. You quote rules without making that connection clear, putting the work on the reader instead, and making it easier for the reader would be nice.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Sorry... Please let me know if it's better now, but feel free to update the text in any case. No problem at all!