# Can Pact of the Chain Warlocks forgo one of their attacks to not break Invisibility?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, familiars, invisibility

I was wondering if you use the second bulletin of the pact of the chain if it would break the invisibility spell.

Pact of the Chain feature in question

> Additionally, when you take the Attack action, **you can forgo one of your own attacks** to allow your familiar to use its reaction to make one attack with its reaction.

Invisibility Spell

> A creature you touch becomes invisible until the spell ends. Anything the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on the target’s person. **The spell ends for a target that attacks** or casts a spell.

So my question boils down to does the invisibility spell break when you take the Attack action or when you attack?

Comment: A very interested find! And on new characters creation day too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Yes, this works.

First, the end condition for *invisibility* requires that you actually make an attack:

> The spell ends for a target that attacks

And as you have observed, you may forego an attack to allow your familiar to attack instead:

> you can forgo one of your own attacks to allow your familiar to use its reaction to make one attack with its reaction.

Here, *the familiar is making an attack, not the warlock* since that is what “forego” means, and [an Attack action is different from an attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/105782/62294).

And if you somehow had an extra attack feature (through multiclassing, not Thirsting Blade), making the second attack for that is optional anyway:

> Beginning at 5th level, you **can** attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.