# Can a Pact of the Chain Warlock use his/her familiar to deliver the warlock's own physical opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, familiars, opportunity-attack

When an enemy leaves the reach of a [Pact of the Chain warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#Pact-of-the-chain), and the warlock gets a physical opportunity attack, can the [familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) deliver it to that enemy if both use their reactions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No, your familiar can only attack when you take the Attack action

Normally familiars cannot attack. *Find Familar* says

> **A familiar can't attack**, but it can take other actions as normal.

The Pact of the Chain warlock has a feature that creates an exception to this rule (PHB, p. 107):

> Additionally, **when you take the Attack action**, you can forgo one of your own attacks to allow your familiar to make one attack of its own.

Taking the Attack action is however different from making an opportunity attack. The Attack action [is a specific action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/what-does-upper-case-a-attack-action-vs-lower-case-a-attack-mean) you take during your own turn. So this exception does not apply to opportunity attacks.